# why is parameter being pass as "/"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a products and categories controllers, when I create a new product, the :category_id is passed as "/".  And I cannot figure out why.  Routes.rb is fine, models are standard, and controller#create is ok (posted below).  What could be wrong?

```
def new
    @product = Product.new
  end


def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @product.category_id = params[:category_id]


    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to category_products_path(@category), notice: 'P$
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_enti$
      end
    end
  end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@category, @product], url: category_products_path([@category, @product]) do |form| %>
  <% if product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

rake routes:

```
 category_products GET    /categories/:category_id/products(.:format)                                              products#index
                        POST   /categories/:category_id/products(.:format)                                              products#create
   new_category_product GET    /categories/:category_id/products/new(.:format)                                          products#new
  edit_category_product GET    /categories/:category_id/products/:id/edit(.:format)                                     products#edit
       category_product GET    /categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)                                          products#show
                        PATCH  /categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)                                          products#update
                        PUT    /categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)                                          products#update
                        DELETE /categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)                                          products#destroy
```

Comment: rake routes is huge, so I just included category_product

Comment: You mean remove before filters?  I did that and still got the same error

Comment: doing form_for [@category, @product] gives me a error 'unknown path products_path'

Comment: @Belvin In case you want to url explicitly with form for then i think you don't need to provide `@product` object  try 
`<%= form_for [@category, @product], url: category_products_path(@category) do |form| %>` as your routes defined.

Comment: OK, now it says missing required keys :category_id

Comment: @Belvin What do you see url: in browser for new action? can you paste that url here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= form_for Product.new, url: category_products_path(params[:category_id]) do |form| %>
  <% if product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller: -

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(product_params)
  @product.category_id = params[:category_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to category_products_path(@product.category), notice: 'P$
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_enti$
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Alright, well it was a combination of several answers but I checked yours, as it was the one that got me the correct parameters.

Comment: @Belvin Glad to know that, feel free to upvote/accept answer :D

Answer (score 1):

```
category_products_path([@category, Product.new]) #=> "categories/1%2f/products"
```

Where `%2f` code of `/`. `[@category, Product.new]` is an array and passes as a single parameter.

```
<%= form_for [@category, @product], url: category_products_path(@category, @product) do |form| %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for [@category, @product], url: category_products_path(@category) do |form| %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for [@category, @product], url: category_products_path(@category.id) do |form| %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for [@category, @product], url: category_products_path(category_id: @category.id) do |form| %>
<% end %>
```

Each would work.

Also, before `redirect_to category_products_path(@category)` `@category` not seted. So, change current path to:
`redirect_to category_products_path(@product.category_id)`

And update your action `new`:

```
def new
  @category = Category.find_by(id: params[:category_id])
  @product = Product.new
end
```

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I did change my _form.html.erb, and urls/paths but still same error.  I will research this and return :-[ thanks

Comment: @Belvin Can you try the solution given by me??

Comment: @Belvin, I updated my answer. You do not set `@category` in `new`. So `@category #=> nil `.

Comment: Gabbar - yes I tried your solution but still get an error.  Also I have set category in #new but it gives me this error for product = Product.new, 'home/yod/sidewalk/app/controllers/products_controller.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting ')' @product = Product.new ^~~~~~~~'

Comment: @Belvin, or better provide all related code(models, full controller etc) inside your question, because there are lot of mistakes and solving one not solve other.